# How to recursively render an action in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Suppose I have a model Person which has a one to many relationship with itself (i.e. Parent -> Child).  When `show.html.erb` is rendered on a given `@person` I would like it to also include the result of rendering of `show.html.erb` for the parent.

Essentially I would like the correct syntax for

`<%= render @person.person %>`

I actually tried manually doing

`<%= render :file => "/persons/1.html.erb" %>`

and it didn't work.  Can someone help me understand the syntax of `render`?  Thanks.

(Note that I actually have a more complicated model and I am rendering SVG files, not html.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put most of the content of show.html.erb in a file called _person.html.erb and then in show.html.erb have this:

```
<%= render :partial => 'person', :locals => {:person => @person} %>
```

Use person instead of @person in _person.html.erb

(Note that the file name starts with an underscore.)

Comment: You may need additional checks for stopping, like: <% if person.parent %><%= render...%> <% end %>

Comment: Great, thanks.  I got close to this on my own, but then I was getting stuck in an infinite loop.  Moving the recursive code to a partial that uses `person` instead of `@person` solves this.

Answer (score 0):

Create a method in Person model to fetch an array of related people, e.g. parents:

```
def parents(person)
   Person.find(:all, :conditions => ...
end
```

In controller, fetch the parents:

```
@parents = Person.parents(someone)
```

In person view (`show.html.erb`), loops the parents array and pass each to the partial view as a parameter:

```
<% @parents.each do |parent| %>
   <%= render :partial => 'info', :locals => { :person => parent } %>
<% end %>
```

Create a partial view: `_info.html.erb`, the `person` is a local variable storing a person record, and can be access within the partial form.